# Google Chrome prompts for username/password even though page doesn't request it

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, passwords

I previously set a directory on my web server to require a username/password during development phase.  I have since removed the .htaccess file to remove the password, I have also checked the cPanel to make sure there are no settings for a user/password.

Despite this, Chrome keeps asking for a username/password.  If I click Cancel, the page continues to load anyway.

This only happens on Chrome Windows and Mac.  I have cleared the entire cache for Chrome but to no avail.  I am not able to replicate the problem on Firefox 4 or Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: Do you have any authentication methods setup, even though there is no password?

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've posted the answer to my problem. Thought it was a server issue but it was actually human error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was silly enough to have left the  URL pointing to a domain which does ask for a username/password but the domain it was pointing to was for the development site.  Not sure why the other browsers didn't do the same thing but updating the base href has solved the problem.